# How to join different tables by field value using Laravel query builder?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I have a table containing the fields below. I just want to join table by the type field value, for example, if type field contains experience value then join should be with experience table by reference association_id field and for the education also same.

```
 - id
 - title
 - association_id
 - type (experience,education)
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: You have just two `enum` type in type column ? and if it can be implemented using sql the obviously possible in query builder.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Laravel relationships on a table with two types of flags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35057540/laravel-relationships-on-a-table-with-two-types-of-flags)

Comment: this is not a duplicate question, because i asked for query builder not for Eloquent

Answer (score 0):

You can use polymorphic relations

Main Model :

```
class Association extends Model {
    public function associable()
    {
        return $this->morphTo();
    }
}
```

Exprience Model :

```
class Exprience extends Model {
    public function associates()
    {
        return $this->morphMany(Association::class, 'associable');
    }
}
```

Education Model :

```
class Education extends Model {
    public function associates()
    {
        return $this->morphMany(Association::class, 'associable');
    }
}
```

Also you should add two extra fields to your main model table :

```
associable_id - integer
associable_type - string
```

Extra Information : https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent-relationships#polymorphic-relations

Comment: sir i'm using query builder not Eloquent, if you can post about query builder joins.